# Reflection - Getting New Instance of unknown classes with unknown number of constructor parameters

Tags: java, oop, reflection

First of all, I am new to Reflection. I have been working on a large project and I needed to use reflection on some parts (Yes I definitely need it). So I thought, I should create a Reflection Helper class which will be able to create new instances of any class with any number of parameters within my project.

As an example to my question: Normally(as far as I know), to create an instance of a class which has 2 strings as parameters in its constructor;

```
Class.getConstructor(String.class, String.class).newInstance("Arg_1", "Args_2");
```

will do the job. However, in my case I need a method which will work for any class with any constructor. So I created these methods but it doesn't seem to work, I keep getting `NoSuchMethodException`. I need help at making it work.

```
private static String packagePrefix = "com.***";

public static Class<?> getClass(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return Class.forName(packagePrefix + "." + className);
}

public static Object getClassInstance(String className, Object... args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
    Class<?>[] cArgs = new Class[args.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        cArgs[i] = args[i].getClass();
    }
    return getClass(className).getConstructor(cArgs).newInstance(args);
}
```

Comment: What `Object... args` are you calling the `getClassInstance ` method with?

Comment: `Skill skill = (Skill) ReflectionHelper.getClassInstance(skillPackagePrefix + skillType.getName(), monster, procChance, params);`
Where, the related Skill class has a constructor as -> `(Monster me, Integer procChance, Integer duration, Integer severity)`

Also params has 2 integers one for duration and the other for severity

Comment: You can get rid of all the suppressed warnings by using `Class<?>` and `Class<?>[]`. Raw types should never be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you can't "create new instances of any class with any number of parameters". If there is not such constructor then you will not be able to call it.

Next, `Class.getConstructor` find the constructor with given formal parameter types, not assignment-compatible types. So if you have `Foo(Number)` you'll not find this constructor with `Foo.class.getConstructor(Long.class)`. You'll have to iterate over `Class.getConstructors` and search for the constructor which has parameter types assignment-compatible types of your parameters.

Luckily, this was done a thousand times already. See [ConstructorUtils.invokeConstructor](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/ConstructorUtils.html#invokeConstructor-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object:A-) from [Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/), for instance. The implementation is far from trivial.

Comment: You were indeed right. getConstructor method couldn't find the right constructor because class names were different in runtime. I went with the manual way and iterated Constructors and verified args by Class#isAssignableFrom method. Everything seems to work now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you are saying that you have class that takes 4 arguments

```
Skill(Monster m, Integer procChance, Integer duration, Integer severity)
```

but you are trying to reflectively create it using only 3 arguments:

```
Skill skill = (Skill) ReflectionHelper.getClassInstance(skillPackagePrefix + skillType.getName(), monster, procChance, params);
```

Even thought that `param` is an array of 2 integers (as you commented) it will be treated by Java as array argument and wont be merged into `Object... args` varargs. The above code will work only for the following constructor:

```
Skill(Monster m, Integer procChance, Integer[] params)
```

Comment: Passing a single array of objects for Object... args just worked for me.
Called it like this:
`ReflectionHelper.getClassInstance(skillPackagePrefix + skillType.getName(), reflectionParams);`

And the method constructor:
`getClassInstance(String className, Object... args)`

Comment: That works. You can't mix vara args and arrays together and expect them to merged as you had originally.